# Error when pressing IE button Object Variable or With block variable not set

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer

I know there are other questions that are similar to mine, but I am quite new to this, and a lot of them don't make sense to me.

That being said, I have researched this error and it says I need to Declare an Object Variable, Set the Object and then use With at the correct points, I have as far as I am aware tried that, but still get the error

> Object variable or With block variable not set

My Code is

```
Public Sub a()

Dim Button4 As Object
Dim ie As New InternetExplorer

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

ie.navigate "https://reporting.med.siemens.com/sap(bD1lbiZjPTEwMSZkPW1pbg==)/bc/bsp/sie/med_cm/start.htm"
ie.Visible = True

Do While ie.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE Or ie.Busy: DoEvents: Loop


With ie.Document

Set Button4 = ie.Document.getElementById("seite-itm-2")
Button4.Click

End With    
 MsgBox "complete"
End Sub
```

What I am trying to do is press the below "Button" on an internet page,

```
<TD onclick="return htmlbSL(this,7,'seite:sel_tab_2','','3','sel_tab_2')" id=seite-itm-2 class=urTbsLabelOff onkeydown="if (sapUrMapi_checkKey(event,'keydown',new Array('32'))){return htmlbSL(this,7,'seite:sel_tab_2','','3','sel_tab_2')};sapUrMapi_TabStrip_keySelect('seite',2,4,event);" noWrap><SPAN id=seite-itm-2-txt title="Bookmarks     " class=urTbsTxtOff>Bookmarks </SPAN></TD>
```

Can some one please help?

Thank You

Comment: Delete `With ie.Document` and `End With`. The error is being raised by this with block. The `With` block isn't being utilized at all from what I can see so you should just get rid of it.

Comment: @MoondogsMaDawg - The `With` block is superfluous but it should not cause error as written.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Is it being caused by the mix of early and late bindings? `Dim ie As New InternetExplorer` & `Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")`?